# Play framework, Akka Persistence, PersistenceQuery, unable to convert Source to Future Object for Action.async

Tags: playframework, akka, cqrs, akka-stream, akka-persistence

I am trying to get list of persistent events and send it as response(`Action.async`). But I am not able to convert `PersistenceQuery` results to `Future` object. Here is the code

```
val queries = PersistenceQuery(actorSystem).readJournalFor[CassandraReadJournal](CassandraReadJournal.Identifier)
val source: Source[EventEnvelope, NotUsed] = queries.eventsByPersistenceId("MYID", 0, Long.MaxValue)
val mappedSource: Source[JsValue, NotUsed] = source.mapAsync(1) { e =>
      e.event match {
        case l: String =>
           Future(Json.parse(l))
      }
   }
val finalResult: Future[List[JsValue]] = mappedSource.take(10).runFold(List[JsValue]())((a, b) => {
      println(a)
      a :+ b
    })
finalResult
```

I am able to see prints within `runFold`, but `finalResult` was never returned. I even tried to `Await`, even after waiting for minutes, it never returned. This `finalResult` shows all the user activity wanted to send it as response as `Action.async`.
Please let me know what is the way to convert `Source` to `Future` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix for this problem is preferred to use `currentEventsByPersistenceId`, this returns all current events. `eventsByPersistenceId` with `take` terminates stream. But in my case `take` function requires 10 events to be collected, in my case I had less than 10, so stream doesn't get terminated until it accumulates at least 10 events. So result was never getting returned.